# Lookback doesn't work at all / Lookback_Weak returns nil

Tags: ios, cocoapods, lookback

I followed the [CocoaPods-based installation instructions for Lookback](https://lookback.io/nevyn/tweetbot/docs/install-using-cocoapods), the app compiles and links, yet all my calls to the Lookback API do nothing. Nothing happens when I shake the device even though I have `shakeToRecord = YES`. If I use `[Lookback lookback]` instead of `[Lookback_Weak lookback]`, I get a linker error saying that the class Lookback doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Lookback requires two "Other Linker Flags" (`OTHER_LDFLAGS`) settings: `-ObjC` and `-framework Lookback`. Both these are automatically set by CocoaPods, but if you set your own flags without including `$(inherited)` in your overrides, CocoaPods' settings will be lost.

I recommend that you add `$(inherited)` to the top of your other linker flags; or remove your customizations entirely (select the "Other Linker Flags" line and press backspace).

[image: $(inherited) as used in Other Linker Flags in Xcode]

Comment: I am also using cocoapods to instal lookback. No problems during the installation, but I get the linker error: ld: framework not found lookback and "linker command failed with exit code 1" Have you encountered such an error with lookback in your project